# Java Applet Layout Doesn't Appear As It Is Supposed To o_O

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am taking a Java class this semester and was working on a take-home quiz.
In it we create a calculator of sorts which is supposed to look like the 1st image attached[image: calculator_applet_intended]

As you can see the base panel is supposed to be divided into 2 rows and 1 column.
The upper panel is divided into 3 rows and 2 columns.
The lower panel has 4 buttons for the calculations to be performed.

For this quiz I created 2 files, WholePanel.java and LayoutPanel.java.
Here is the code for WholePanel.java:

```
package layoutpanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import static java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
 * @author ross satchell
 */

public class WholePanel extends JPanel{
    public JTextField textBox1, textBox2, resultBox;
    public double num1, num2, result;
    public JLabel label1, label2, label3;
    public JButton addButton, subButton, multipButton, dividButton;


public WholePanel(){                            // constructor
    JPanel upperPanel, lowerPanel, subPanel;
    upperPanel = new JPanel();   // the panel for the top section
    lowerPanel = new JPanel();   // the panel for the lower section
    subPanel = new JPanel();     // panel to hold both upperPanel and lowerPanel
    label1 = new JLabel("Enter number 1:");
    label2 = new JLabel("Enter number 2:");
    label3 = new JLabel("Result:");
    textBox1 = new JTextField(10);
    textBox2 = new JTextField(10);
    resultBox = new JTextField(10);
    addButton  =new JButton("+");
    subButton = new JButton("-");
    multipButton = new JButton("*");
    dividButton = new JButton("/");



    upperPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    upperPanel.add(label1);
    upperPanel.add(textBox1);       // set up layout and 
    upperPanel.add(label2);         // components for upperPanel
    upperPanel.add(textBox2);
    upperPanel.add(label3);
    upperPanel.add(resultBox);

    lowerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    lowerPanel.add(addButton);
    lowerPanel.add(subButton);           // set up topLowerPanel 
    lowerPanel.add(multipButton);        // components and layout
    lowerPanel.add(dividButton);

    subPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    subPanel.add(upperPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    subPanel.add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);               // add each panel to the main subPanel
    this.add(subPanel);

    addButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());      // add button listeners
    subButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());      // for each of the 
    multipButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());   // four buttons
    dividButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());    //
}


private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JButton buttonX = (JButton) e.getSource();
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(textBox1.getText());  // read values in textBox1
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(textBox2.getText());  // and textBox2

        if (buttonX == addButton){
            result = num1 + num2;
        }else if (buttonX == subButton){                // performed required calculation
            result = num1 - num2;
        }else if (buttonX == multipButton){
            result = num1 * num2;
        }else if (buttonX == dividButton){
            result = num1 / num2;
        }
        resultBox.setText("" + result);
        }   //  end actionPerformed() method

    }   // end ButtonListener class

}       // end WholePanel class
```

And here is the code for LayoutPanel.java

```
package layoutpanel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LayoutPanel extends JApplet{


public void init(){

WholePanel wholePanel = new WholePanel();
getContentPane().add(wholePanel);
setSize(300,200);
}
```

When I run the applet it appears as thus:
[image]
As you can see, it appears as if both topPanel and lowerPanel are somehow both in the top row of subPanel.

For curiosity's sake I tried changing the subPanel to a BorderLayout and positioned topPanel to the NORTH and lowerPanel to the SOUTH. However when I ran the applet it still appeared exactly the same!

I have pored over the code trying to see what I have done wrong, but I'm completely stumped.
I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes will see what careless mistake I have made.

Any and all suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a compound of issues...

`JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`, so since you never change the layout manager for `WholePanel`, that's what it keeps on using.

You should probably change it to use something like `BorderLayout`

```
public WholePanel() {                            // constructor
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Now, based on the original layout, I might be tempted to use a `GridBagLayout` for the `subPanel`

```
subPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
subPanel.add(upperPanel, gbc);
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
subPanel.add(lowerPanel, gbc);               // add each panel to the main subPanel
this.add(subPanel);
```

which can result in something like...

[image: Layout]